# iOS How to set a Sidebar Menu programmatically in the AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, sidebar

I am looking for a possibility to set a sidebar menu programmatically in the AppDelegate. I want to have a top navigation controller with a sidebar button on the left. when the button is pressed, a UIView appear of the left side. A Collection of ViewControllers where initialized in the AppDelegate. they should then appear in the sidebar menu.

Here is a mockup of how I imagine it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBI53.png

Does anyone have an idea how to implement it?

many thanks in advance
best regards
moritz

Comment: Please rephrase your question and consider not asking for tutorials. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is the world famous slider (DrawerController) code used most of iOS apps..

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

If you do not want to use it (I think you should) there are tons of ways to achieve it but it takes time.

Comment: hi thanks for the quick response. but the navigationbar should not move. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: That library has so many configurations...You can try it out It should be possible. otherwise you can have a UIView laying under self.view on (0,0) coordinates and implement self.view swap gesture..